# Secure boot disabled for Potential BIOS compromise on Tails OS machine

Tags: malware, system-compromise, bios, secure-boot

I have an ASUS computer that I use strictly for booting Tails OS from a USB. A few weeks ago I went into the BIOS and noticed that secure boot was disabled.

This computer has secure boot enabled by default. The chances of me having done this are slim to none, so I must go with the other option that the computer was tampered with as it was not phsyically protected at all times.

When i re-enabled secure boot, I now see a warning that there is an invalid signature (I previously did not get this warning). However once I OK the prompt, I'm able to boot into Tails.

From what I have read on the tails website, compromised BIOS and compromised firmware are the main attacks Tails OS cannot be protected from.

Now my questions is

Does this sound like a step in the attack of an attacker trying to compromise the BIOS/Firmware of the Tails system? Meaning would the attacker need to disable secure boot to compromise the BIOS or firmware?

If so, what would they have done after disabling the secure boot and how can I now check the integrity of the BIOS and Firmware now?